# Setup linux as bluetooth NAP and connect to windows over bluetooth ethernet (Bluez5)

Tags: configuration, network-interface, bluetooth, bridge, bluez

I want to connect my linux laptop (debian 8) with my windows laptop (windows 10) with ethernet over bluetooth. (This is a must have setup.) On the linux side I have bluez5. I found out that there is a `org.bluez.Networkserver1` method to register a server ([network-api](https://github.com/r10r/bluez/blob/master/doc/network-api.txt)). There I choose "NAP". But I don't know what to write as bridge?

I tried to setup some bridge connection on the linux laptop but this doesn't work. Can anybody give my some steps or an good tutorial?

All I could find was outdated (bluez4) or for linux - linux connection.

**Note:** Sharing internet is not neccessary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is no need for a NAP for a point-to-point conenction. In this case it is enough if both devices are in mode "PANU".

Just execute the bluez-test script "test-network" with thhe mac of the device which you want to connect to as argument. (After pairing)

Then everything works fine without nedd for interaction.